# What kind of algebraic structure is this?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that over a set are defined two binary operations - "+" and "*", where the first is associative and commutative, and the following law holds:

$(x + y) * z = x + (y * z)$

This law is stronger than the law of distributivity from the right of "*" with respect to "+", that is, also the law of distributivity from right for such a structure holds.

Does such a structure occur in algebra, and if does, what is the name of this law?

An example of such structure is one with the two operations defined over sets this manner: "+" is union, and x * y is defined as $x \cup \{y\}$.

Comment: Something like that occurs on the so called group action

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called  $\color{red}{compatibility}$ of a group action, this is when you have an action (map $\phi$) acting on a group $G$ and a set $X$ defined as follows $ \phi:G \times X \to X$ and we denote $\phi(g,x)$ as $g 
\cdot x$.

A group action must satisfy the following properties

(1)$\color{red}{(gh).x = g.(h.x)}$ for all $g, h \in G$ and all $x \in X$

This property is very simillar to the one you are asking about because the dot notation is abstract !

(2) $e.x = x$ for all $x \in X$ and  $e$ is the identity in $G$